# Create chart for last 30 days if some day is empty

Tags: php, charts

How to make chart for 31 days if some day is not in database, example i have added this code

```
<?php foreach ($stats as $row):
    echo '['.$row['day'].','.$row['total'].'],';
endforeach; ?>
```

This back me just two result because in database i have only two result

```
['15','1'],
['18','1'],
```

But i need to make if no result output should be

```
['1','0'],
['2','0'],
['3','0'],
['4','0'],
....,
['15','1'],
```

Up to 31

Comment: Try to explain your question again and post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop and print, like this:

```
<?php
for ( $x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++)
{
  $value = 0;
  foreach ( $stats as $data)
  {
    if ( $data["day"] == $x)
    {
      $value = $data["total"];
    }
  }
  echo "[" . $x . "," . $value . "],";
}
?>
```

Comment: That is exactly what i need. Thanks